# Surfaceview/TextureView for subtitles alpha does not work

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, android-ndk, surfaceview

**Goal**: trying to build video player with subtitles for android. Video can be low resolution but the subtitles should be resolution of phone (such that if video is 720p, the subtitles should render to screen size say 1080p).

**Issue**: *Render on Textureview or Surfaceview is not see through where you could get it to blend with the background views.* I am using FFMPEG to render a frame at say 720p but phone device is 1080p. I need to display subtitles that are different resolution than the subtitles resolution so pixel blending is difficult.

I first tried to scale the frame (AVFrame) with sws_convert but each frame took 80ms so that is not an option (since it is running software).

Then I tried two surface views, one for the video and one for subtitles where video would be 720p and subtitles SurfaceView is 1080p, then the video scales up to the phone size. The issue here is that the subtitles are not translucent. Black opacity 0 would be transparent but white with alpha 0 is still white. Why is this?

```
//Code from Java, the view that extends FrameLayout
public VideoView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    mVideoSurface = new SurfaceView(context);
    mSubtitlesSurface = new SurfaceView(context);
    addView(mVideoSurface);
    addView(mSubtitlesSurface);
    mVideoSurface.getHolder().addCallback(mSurfaceCallback);
    mSubtitlesSurface.getHolder().addCallback(mSurfaceCallback);
    mSubtitlesSurface.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
    mSubtitlesSurface.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    //etc
}
```

Eventually I tried as a test to render a square to the subtitle surface view (C++)

```
// Render the video frame, now render the subtitle frame
ANativeWindow_Buffer buffer;
ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry(subWindow, width, height, WINDOW_FORMAT_RGBA_8888);
if ((ret = ANativeWindow_lock(subWindow, &buffer, NULL)) < 0) {
    return ret;
}
for (int j = height/2; j < height/2 + 100; j++) {
    for (int i = width/2; i < width/2 + 100; i++) {
        uint8_t * d =  (uint8_t*)buffer.bits + j * (buffer.stride * 4) + i * 4;
        d[0] = 0xff;
        d[1] = 0xff;
        d[2] = 0xFF;
        d[3] = 0;           /* alpha */

    }
}
ANativeWindow_unlockAndPost(subWindow);
```

So above code should render a white square in the image with 0 alpha (so should be invisible), but it is shown. If I change it to yellow with alpha 0 it will be visible but not the correct color. If I change to white with 1 alpha, it is white and opaque. If I use black with alpha 0xCC, it is invisible, only if alpha is 0xFF then it is visible as black. Seems to have no translucency even though I added it to the SurfaceHolder. Why is it like this? I can add more code if needed.

Is my only option to do what I want to render frame as a texture in OpenGL and (GLSurfaceView), resize the image to phone resolution and blend the alpha subtitles onto the frame as a texture?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have to use ffmpeg? why not give a try and use exoplayer for example and save a lot of dirty work?

Comment: I need the extra codecs that ffmpeg has

Comment: and you have to use the second SurfaceView? what those subtitles come from? how you want to draw them?

Comment: Using libass to render the subtitles via ndk, subtitles render at display resolution and video at usually lower resolution. Rendering subtitles with alpha rgba_8888 doesn't work.

Comment: I tried something similar and it works for me. I created two `SurfaceView` like you did (with media overlay enabled on the second), and then used OpenGL with the overlaid Surface to `glClearColor(0.5, 0, 0, 0.5)` and there's a red-tint over the underlying video surface. The two surfaces are blended together as I expect.

Comment: I figured it out, realized I forgot to alpha blend the pixels (alpha channel, before I always assumed it was 0xFF) because libass has its rectangles overlapping each other. So my source was wrong!